# I am in need to import src library. I have used pip install src. but an error use to appear

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using a Colab notebook for building a segmenting model. I am in need to import `src` library. I have used `pip install src`. but an error use to appear, I have downloaded the package on my disk but I don't know how to insert it on the notebook to be used.

### Error

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/2b/a6ccfc80af698319c54f00da05f6c798cf72291938893f8bd3f730c2daf9/src-0.0.7.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: src
  Building wheel for src (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for src
  Running setup.py clean for src
Failed to build src
Installing collected packages: src
    Running setup.py install for src ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o7x6uewa/src/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o7x6uewa/src/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-e8u3fix1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install src==0.0.6`

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

> I am in need to import src library.

No, you don't. There is a [package named src in pypi](https://pypi.org/project/src/) which has been made by a benevolent soul designed to not work, because that is not what you want to do.

---

When you're instructed to use `pip install src`, what it means is that you're supposed to install the directory `src` under a local repository as a local package. If that command doesn't work, it's because you're running it in the wrong directory, you skipped downloading the source code of the program you're trying to install, or you failed to read some instruction from the mantainer.

Packages crafted this way have well defined `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, `pyproject.toml` and all modules stuck inside a `src` folder, which makes it easy to install the whole program as a python package (or module) by simply writing `pip install src` in the **root folder of the program's source code**.

If there isn't a *src* folder correctly configured as a python package or module, pip will default to searching for a package named *src* on the pypi default repository (pypi.org). Thankfully, one person decided to make a dummy package on that namespace to avoid someone uploading a virus to your environment, making your code not work so you can refrain from doing something you're not supposed to.

So to fix that undesired behaviour you should make sure that the package you're supposed to install is present in your environment. For cloud environments, the current folder where you run `pip install src` should be the one where you downloaded the source files for the thing you're trying to install.